# Chain rule for Hessian matrix

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ smooth and $\phi \in GL(n)$. What is the Hessian matrix $H_{f\circ \phi} = \left(\frac{\partial ^2 (f\circ \phi)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right)_{ij}$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Denote $H_g(x)$ the Hessian matrix of a function $g$. Denote $g=f\circ \phi$. By the chain rule, we have
$$D(f\circ\phi)(x)\cdot h=D(f(\phi (x))\cdot D(\phi (x))\cdot h=D(f(\phi (x)))\cdot \phi (x)\cdot h$$
hence $D(g)(x)=D(f(\phi (x)))\cdot \phi (x)$. In particular,
$$\partial_j g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\partial_kf(\phi (x))a_{kj},$$
where $a_{kj}$ is the $(k,j)$-th entry of $\phi (x)$.We can do the same, for a fixed $k$, for the map $x\mapsto \partial_kf(\phi (x))$. We get
\begin{align}
\partial_{ij}f(\phi (x))&=\sum_{k,l=1}^n(H_f(\phi (x)))_{lk}a_{li}a_{kj}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(\phi(x)^t H_f(\phi (x)))_{ik}a_{kj}\\
&=(\phi(x)^tH_f(\phi (x))\phi (x))_{ij}.
\end{align}

Comment: I think you are missing a term. If you see the picture in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146526/finding-the-cost-of-hessian-vector-product-computation the result should be what you have plus the gradient of f times the "tensor hessian" of $\phi$.

Comment: @ThomasAhle $\phi$ is linear. Maybe that makes that term disappear.

Comment: If it still matters...this is correct, the term "disappears" given the linearity. In particular if the map is also orthogonal, one can proove that the laplacian is invariant under rotation