# What is the Hessian of $x \mapsto\log \det \left( A^T A + R^T \operatorname{diag}(x)^{-1} R \right)$?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4526815/439496) I asked regarding the hessian of a similar log determinant. The log determinant I am considering is given by
$$
L(\vec{x}) = \log \det \left( A^T A + R^T D_x^{-1} R \right),
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^q$ with all positive entries, $D_x = \operatorname{diag}(x)$ is a diagonal matrix, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}$.

**What is the Hessian of $L(x)$ with respect to $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_q)^T$?**

I have determined that the gradient can be written as
$$
\nabla_x L(x) = - \operatorname{diag}\left( D_x^{-1} R \left( A^T A + R^T D_x^{-1} R \right)^{-1} R^T D_x^{-1}  \right).
$$
Using an identity for the $\operatorname{diag}$ operator, this can also be written as
$$
\nabla_x L(x) = - \left( \left( D_x^{-1} R  \right) \odot \left( D_x^{-1} R  \right) \right) \operatorname{diag}\left( \left( A^T A + R^T D_x^{-1} R \right)^{-1}  \right).
$$
Any advice on how to proceed from here? I am thinking the next step to find the gradient is to apply a product rule to this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$
\def\L{{\cal L}}  \def\l{\lambda}  \def\n{\nabla}  \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the following symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= \Diag{x} = D_x \\
Y &= X^{-1} &\qiq dY = -Y\:dX\:Y \\
B &= \LR{A^TA+R^TYR} &\qiq dB = \;\:\, R^TdYR \\
C &= B^{-1} &\qiq dC = -C\;dB\:C \\
M &= RCR^T &\qiq dM = \; R\;dC\:R^T \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product $(:)$ with these properties
$$\eqalign{
P:Q &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}Q_{ij} \;=\; \trace{P^TQ} \\
Q:Q &= \frob{Q}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
P:Q &= Q:P \;=\; Q^T\!:P^T \\
R:\LR{PQ} &= \LR{RQ^T}:P \;=\; \LR{P^TR}:Q \\
}$$
Use the above notation to write the objective function.
With the aid of [Jacobi's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula), it's straightforward to calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
\L &= \log(\det(B)) \\
d\L &= B^{-T} : dB \\
  &= B^{-1} : \LR{-R^TY\:dX\:YR} \\
  &= -\LR{YMY}:dX \\
  &= -\diag{YMY}:dx \\
\grad{\L}{x}  &= -\diag{YMY} \;\doteq\; g \\
\grad{\L}{X}  &=\; \Diag{g} \;\doteq\; G \\
}$$
This result validates your own gradient calculation.

At this point, recall that
$$ \diag{ABC} = \diag{C^TB^TA^T} $$
Then to calculate the Hessian, start with the differential of $g$
$$\eqalign{
dg &= -\diag{\,YM\:\c{dY} + Y\:\c{dM}\:Y + \c{dY}\,MY} \\
 &= -\diag{2YM\;\c{dY} + Y\:\c{dM}\:Y} \\
 &= \diag{2YMY\:\c{dX}\:Y - YMY\:\c{dX}\:YMY} \\
 &= 2YG\,\c{dx} - \LR{YMY\odot YMY}\c{dx} \\
\grad{g}{x} &= 2YG - \LR{YMY\odot YMY} \;\doteq\; H \\
}$$
Since the $H$ matrix is constructed from *symmetric* and/or *diagonal* matrices, it is obviously a symmetric matrix (which is required of a Hessian).

Comment: Do you have any suggested references for learning matrix calculus?

Comment: Exploring posts on this site using the _Matrix Calculus_ tag would be a good start (and it's free).  Beyond that, the standard text is probably 
Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_
although personally I prefer 
Hjorungnes's _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal L$ the function from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4526815/439496), $f: x\in\mathbb R^q \to \left(\prod_{j\neq i} x_j\right)_{1\le i\le q} \in \mathbb R^q$ and $g(x): x\in\mathbb R^q \to \prod_{i=1}^q x_i \in \mathbb R$. You can easily prove that: $$L(x) = \mathcal L\left(g(x)\mathbf 1, f(x)\right) - q\sum_{i=1}^q \log x_i$$

You can use the [Hessian chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172324/chain-rule-for-hessian-matrix) to have your Hessian.